# Finding row in Nested List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nested-lists

If you have a nested `List` of type `T` as such:

```
List<List<T>> foo = new List<List<T>>();
```

And you assume that the elements in the inner list are columns, then what is the most graceful way to obtain the rows? Here's what I mean (if you need more detail):

Adding elements (assuming the list has already been initialized)

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    for (int y = 5; y < 10; y++)
        foo[x][y] = y + x; // some weird value
```

So, therefore, getting a column is simple (and the biggest reason why I replaced this method with a two-dimensional array):

```
// 5th column
foo[5];
```

But how would you get a row? I was trying something like this (5th row):

```
// 5th row ??
foo.Where(sublist => true).Where(item => item.Y == 5);
// (Assume the objects have a Y property that reflects its coordinate)
```

but it seems as though the first `Where` clause returns type `List<List<T>>` and not `List<T>` as I intended.

So there are two paths for this question (either answer will suffice):

1. Avoiding loops, how do you enumerate through all the items in a list?
2. How do you get a row using any other simple method?

If all else fails I could also make a class to represent this nested list, but I'd like to prevent that because it would be a singleton.

Comment: I like @juharr's solution because you want the 5th row, not a row with a column that has a specific value. Each object in the inner list should not contain the row number unless the row number is from a database table and does not correspond to the position within the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that every column has 5 rows you can just select that index.

```
var fifthRow = foo.Select(x => x[4]).ToList();
```

Or a more safe option would be

```
var fifthRow = foo.Select(x => x.Skip(4).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

As any column that doesn't have at least 5 rows would produce the default value for `T`.

Note this will be a new list with the values of that row, so it cannot be used to update the values in `foo`.